# Is it safe to run tune2fs -l /dev/device on a mounted filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Is it safe to run tune2fs -l /dev/device on a mounted filesystem? That is, listing the current values (I'm trying to do this to see if the filesystem is marked as clean).

If it's ok, is there a definitive source where this is documented so that I can rest assured I won't corrupt something?

Thanks

Comment: corss posting https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327594/is-it-safe-to-run-tune2fs-l-dev-device-on-a-mounted-filesystem/1327729#1327729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dumpe2fs` command can be used on a mounted partition.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally safe to run `tune2fs -l` on a mounted filesystem. In fact, there are several things that can also be modified by `tune2fs` while the filesystem is mounted. See the man page.